# Turkish Vowel Letter Recognition

Tags: c

I would like to generate code;
When you enter sentence, the system will display only consonant letters for these sentence.

I generated code but the code does not recognize Special Turkish Vowel Letter 
 like  İ,Ü,Ö as a Constant letter. Only recognize English Latin vowel letter.

How can I fix that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int vowel (char);

int main () 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
    char s[100], t[100];
    int c, d = 0;
    printf ("Enter sentence vowels will ve removed:\n");
    gets (s);
    for (c = 0; s[c] != '\0'; c++)
    {
        if (vowel (s[c]) == 0)
        {           
            t[d] = s[c];
            d++;
        }
    }
    t[d] = '\0';
    strcpy (s, t);      
    printf ("Letters without vowels: %s\n", s);
    return 0;
}

int vowel (char ch) 
{
    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A'
     || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E'
     || ch == 'ı' || ch == 'I'
     || ch == 'i' || ch == 'İ'
     || ch == 'o' || ch == 'O'
     || ch == 'ö;' || ch == 'Ö'
     || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U'
     || ch == 'ü' || ch == 'Ü')
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indentation might not be important for the compiler, but it is for us humans attempting to read and understand your code. Please [edit] your question to get consistent indentation.

Comment: On another (but unrelated) note, if you have a function which does `if (some_condition) return 1; else return 0;` you can replace it with the single statement `return some_condition;`.

Comment: Lastly about your problem: Are those characters part of an 8.-bit character set (usually values from `128` to `255`, inclusive)? And if they are, have your editor saved them as 8-bit characters in the source file (use a hex-editor to see, and check your editor preferences if it's set to Unicode or UTF-8 or similar)?

Comment: `aeiou` and the upper case equivalent are between 0 - 255 (char type, 8 bits). However, more complex characters like the turkish symbols would be represented by unicode. They may not fit in a single byte. You might need to accept a `wchar_t` in the vowel function instead of `char`.

Comment: Does the program compile?  At least the way it appears here, the line after `'o' || 'O'` seems to have 2 chars within `''`, the second being a `;`

Comment: @Milag I fixed ; issue but sitll same

Comment: @algrebe ii tried wchar_t as well but same.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  ascii codes these letters are ı letter ascii code>> & # 305; ö letter ascii code>> & # 246; ü letter ascii code>> & # 252; İ letter ascii code>> & # 304; Ö letter ascii code>> & # 214; Ü letter ascii code>> & # 220;

Comment: @Satfighter Does my answer help? I used wchar_t and it seems to work

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a *seven* bit encoding, with values in the range of `0` to `127` (or `0177`  in octal).

Comment: Dear @algrebe thank you very much for your quick reply. I had run code on https://onlinegdb.com/BkxnoKZ2L but Turkish vowels show as questionmark at onlinegdb

Comment: @Satfighter I've updated my answer to make it work on onlinegdb. https://onlinegdb.com/rk83S5Zh8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten it to use `wchar_t` instead of char.

Ascii characters are represented in a single byte (char). You may need to convert your code to use `wchar_t`.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int vowel (wchar_t); // <---- accepts wchar_t instead of char

int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
    /* To get it to work on https://www.onlinegdb.com/
     * use setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_US.UTF-8");
     * 
     */
    wchar_t s[100], t[100]; // <---- wchar_t instead of char
    int c, d = 0;
    printf ("Enter sentence vowels will ve removed:\n");

    // TODO : also check the return code. On error, it returns NULL.
    fgetws (s, 100, stdin); // <----- accepting wchar_t string

    for (c = 0; s[c] != '\0'; c++)
    {
        if (vowel (s[c]) == 0)
        {
            t[d] = s[c];
            d++;
        }
    }
    t[d] = '\0';
    // using memcpy instead of strcpy.
    // also see - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcscpy/
    memcpy (s, t, sizeof(t));
    printf ("Letters without vowels: ");
    for (c = 0; c < d; c++)
        putwchar(s[c]); // <---- print wchar_t character on terminal
    putwchar('\n');
    return 0;
}

int vowel (wchar_t ch)
{
    // I've prefixed an L - more than one byte.
    if (ch == L'a' || ch == L'A'
     || ch == L'e' || ch == L'E'
     || ch == L'ı' || ch == L'I'
     || ch == L'i' || ch == L'İ'
     || ch == L'o' || ch == L'O'
     || ch == L'ö' || ch == L'Ö'
     || ch == L'u' || ch == L'U'
     || ch == L'ü' || ch == L'Ü')
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
}
```

Sample output

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
Enter sentence vowels will ve removed:
abcdxyÖÜ
Letters without vowels: bcdxy
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear @algrebe thank you very much for your quick reply. I had run code on https://onlinegdb.com/BkxnoKZ2L  but Turkish vowels shows as questionmark at onlinegdb

```
Enter sentence vowels will ve removed:                                                                                                        
avbcdxyÖÜ                                                                                                                                     
setters without vowels: vbcdxys��
```

Comment: It may be that onlinegdb doesn't support turkish locale. I've changed it to use en_US.UTF-8 and it works there now.